# Default Quasar app in VSCode with recommend extensions has no IntelliSense code completion for Quasar components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, quasar-framework, quasar

I created a default Quasar project in VSCode and have the recommended extensions. The Quasar version is 2.6.0. The [Quasar docs on VSCode configuration](https://quasar.dev/start/vs-code-configuration) state, "If you created your project with Quasar CLI, you already have the recommended VS Code configuration." However, when I create a default project with Quasar CLI, auto-complete does not with Quasar components, just standard Vue components. For example, typing `<q-b` in the template should suggest `<q-btn>`, but there is no suggestion. Typing `<` is enough to bring up a list of suggested Vue components. Interestingly, the Quasar learning project [Takeoff](https://github.com/quasarcast/takeoff) does have auto-complete when I clone it from Github. I am using the same IDE and extensions with both projects, so the project files have to be the issue, but the Quasar docs say auto-complete should work out of the box. What am I missing here?

I expected auto-completion to work out of the box, but it isn't. I have tried switching between Volar and Vetur, but neither provide Quasar component auto-completion. I have tried running both Webpack and Vite servers but it didn't make a difference. I have restarted VSCode after each of these changes.

Comment: Auto-complete or auto-imports? If the first one, auto-complete what exactly?

Comment: Auto-complete Quasar component names in the template. For example, typing "<q-b" in the template should suggest "<q-btn>".

Comment: So, what do you want to work with? Vue2 or 3? Webpack or Vite?

Comment: Vue 3. I am fine with Vite or Webpack, but have tried both and neither worked.

Comment: I can't see any reference to an autocomplete anywhere in the official documentation. Is this coming from TS maybe?

Comment: Perhaps I should have been calling it IntelliSense or code completion. The VS Code config page in the docs lists IntelliSense as a result of installing the "essential VS Code extensions". I've also seen it present in tutorial videos, such as Luke Diabold's "Getting Started" series.

Comment: Yeah, sure it's coming from IntelliSense. But where that one is coming from? I don't see the component auto-completion listed as a feature of Quasar at all. That would be a good starting point to know where that one is coming from.

Comment: You are right, it is not actually a feature. I was confused because if you have a project that uses all of the components, as in the Takeoff project, then they are all suggested in IntelliSense, but when I removed them from templates in the project, they are no longer suggested. If you post an answer I will select it. Thank for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature as Auto-completion of components in Quasar.

Only IntelliSense can provide you some suggestions based on the components it knows the existence or maybe some Typescript configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Volar and install [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) VSCode extension instead. It has auto complete feature.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from my [post](https://jzwangblog.wordpress.com/2024/02/18/how-to-resolve-the-issue-of-quasar-v2-project-lacking-intellisense-in-vs-code/):

> Open the Quasar project and create a new file named 'quasar.d.ts' in the 'src' directory.
>
> If you are working with 'Quasar CLI with Vite', add the following content into the 'quasar.d.ts' file.
>
> `/// <reference types="@quasar/app-vite" />`
>
> If you are working with 'Quasar CLI with Webpack', add the following content into the 'quasar.d.ts' file.
>
> `/// <reference types="@quasar/app-webpack" />`
>
> Restart VS Code and the Intellisense should work fine.